# PHP Round array to nearest hundredth and seperate evenly

Tags: php

I am pulling 10 integers from a MySQL DB:

I want to be able to determine the largest value then round up to the nearest hundredth. With this I want to then be able to create a list of 10 numbers that are evenly separated down to zero.

In Example : 
{ 232, 10, 0, 55, 130, 423, 102, 22, 98, 3 }

Take : 423 => Round up to 500

Then with the number 500 come back with equally separated numbers such as :

500 , 450 , 400, 350, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100, 50, 0

Thank you for the help in advance!

Chris

Comment: I have a bunch of integers and I need to properly format a graph. Therefor on the side I want to find the MAX then evenly show numbers on the side axis. So for example if I had up to 5000, it would be 5000 all the way down to 0. Evenly across 10 seperate numbers.

Comment: I understand the setup. I just don't understand what you're having difficulties with.

Comment: Taking my maximum number, lets say 423 -> becomes 500.  Now taking that 500 and echoing back 10 even numbers.. 500...450...400..350..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
    $array = array(232, 10, 0, 55, 130, 423, 102, 22, 98, 3); 
    $max = max($array);
    $max_rounded = ceil($max/100)*100;
    $diff = ($max_rounded/10);
    while($max_rounded >= 0){
        echo $max_rounded.' ';
        $max_rounded -= $diff;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! One thing, I see the 50 is set. How could we figure that out on the fly as in if we had a massive number 35,000. If it counted at 50s it would be huge. What if we can set it as no matter way we need 10 numbers always.

Comment: This will only work if the number rounds to 500. The difference needs to be calculated.

Comment: Sorry, didn't payed attention to the 10 numbers part, let me see.

Comment: I added : 

        $count = 10;
 $diff = ($max_rounded/$count);

Comment: Well I just edited it to account for a few things, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
$maximal = max($array);
function roundNearestHundredUp($number)
{
    return ceil( $number / 100 ) * 100;
}
$counting = roundNearestHundredUp($maximal);
while($counting >= 0){
    echo $counting;
    $counting -= 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I see that this will get us the max value awesome. However how could I take that number and then evenly segment (10) numbers from that so lets say 5000 seperated evenly all the way to 0.

Comment: `for($i = 5000; $i =< 0;$i-5){ /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: something like `$segments=range($max, 0, ceil($max/$num_of_segments))`

Comment: Looping is verbose. PHP's [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) works the same, but more concisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum number of your results set by using MySQL's `MAX()` function. No sense in returning results you don't need:

```
SELECT MAX(your_column) FROM some_table;
```

Then use PHP to do the math on the number:

```
function getChoices($start, $count)
{
    $start = ceil($start / 100) * 100;

    return range($start, 0, ($start / $count));
}

$choices = getChoices(460, 10);
```

If you don't want to use MySQL's `MAX()`: `$choices = getChoices(max($results), 10);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm having a bit of trouble implementing this, will this count evenly?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "count evenly". The range() function creates a range between x --> y with the third argument being the number of evenly spaced increments. Read about `range()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php . You can use the function by thinking of it like this: `getChoices($maximumNumberOfYourResults, $howManyIncrementsYouWant)`